# Only allow specific types in an ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

Is there a way to subclass the ArrayList class to only allow objects of a specific class (or subclass thereof).
Specifically, I have a base class called RecordStatus and I need to create ArrayLists with objects based on this class.
I know it would be easy to create a class based on `ArrayList<RecordStatus>` but then, every time I retrieve an element from the array, I need to cast it to the original class.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `ArrayList<WhateverSubclassYouWant>`? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Does the arraylist contain different subclasses of `RecordStatus`?

Comment: Can you post some code explaining where you are getting problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList<? extends RecordStatus>` is as close as you can get.

Comment: that defines the generic type of the array, NOT the types in the array.  You can still put subclasses of `RecordStatus` in an `ArrayList<RecordStatus>`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to subclass the ArrayList class to only allow objects
>   of a specific class (or subclass thereof). Specifically, I have a base
>   class called RecordStatus and I need to create ArrayLists with objects
>   based on this class.

That's exactly what the generic construct in Java allows you to do.  Note that you don't have to cast the instances coming out of your `ArrayList<RecordStatus>` as long as all subclasses of `RecordStatus` have the same API.  You only have to do that if the subclasses have different methods/fields.  For example, if `RecordStatus` has a method `setStatus`, and so does a subclass, no casting is necessary, as the dynamic dispatch of Java's polymorphism will make sure the method that gets implemented is correct based on the type of the instance on which the method is invoked at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to cast anything if you set up your types correctly. For example, this should work:

```
List<RecordStatus> myList = new ArrayList<RecordStatus>();
//Add values to the list
RecordStatus myRecordStatus = myList.get(0);
```

But if you really want to subclass ArrayList, you can do the following:

```
private class MyArrayList<R extends RecordStatus> extends ArrayList<R> {
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created arrayList without troubles using a line like this

```
List<RecordStatus> list = new ArrayList<RecordStatus>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Collections.checkedList(List<E> list, Class<E> type)`. This will ensure the Type-Safety.